# is grizzly-EchoServer-sample an http server

Tags: grizzly

I am working in a project using grizzly. At the beginning, I worked with the sample https://grizzly.java.net/quickstart.html. Since I want to built a grizzly-based  https-server, I used another sample https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html for my project.

I am asking whether the server in the first sample that I used at the beginning was an http-server. I think that it was not an http-server but I need a confirmation, so that I can understand the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Echo example was not HTTP based.  It's a simple TCP echo.